# How to make an image appear beneath a hover/active link?

Tags: css, hyperlink, navigation, styling

I currently have a nav bar with [links like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9U6h.png) & I want a hover/active state where an image appears beneath the link [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Ghh.png). How would I write this in?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please let us know, what have you tried so far. It will be helpful for other to give a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done just with css `::after` pseudo element.

html

```
<ul>
  <li class="item" data-icon="❤️">menu text</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.item:hover::before {
  content: attr(data-icon);
}
```

You can just use any [emoji](https://emojipedia.org/heavy-black-heart/) for icons in this case
here's full [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ab0rtfw6/5/)

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one way to do this, the easiest and most unobstrusive is a non JS solution.

I am loading the font awesome logo from the cdn

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Then a link looks like this in the markup:

```
<a class="active" href="#">Home<i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
```

Here I set the opacity for the i element to 0 and give it a transition:

```
i {
color: violet;

opacity: 0;
position: relative;
left: 20px;

transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

And finally, you set the proerties fro the links on hover, you can talget child elements in CSS with ">"

```
a:hover > i {
opacity: 1;
transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

That is all, here is a link:

https://codepen.io/damPop/pen/zMzBGN?editors=0110